# What paramater am I missing for YouTube Data API Insert method

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using Google's Apps Script for this project. I'm using the YouTube data API V3 and of that API I am using the PlaylistItems class. I'm trying to insert a video into a playlist and I've pieced together what I can from the documentation that they have given.

```
YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({
  "part": [
    "snippet"
  ],
  "resource": {
    "snippet": {
      "playlistId": "PL5t3YGq3D2WnrLyuYL9WCgprQ2RUcwl8a",
      "position": 0,
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": testVidId
        // testVidId is the ID of the video I'm trying to insert
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When I run this though, I get an error of

```
Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only
```

My question is: what argument am I missing?

Comment: By looking at the package's actual code, it looks like it's supposed to be `requestBody` instead of `resource` ([see here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/youtube/v3.ts#L13962)). They might have made a mistake in the docs, where they use `resource` as you did

Comment: They changed it in 2018 in [this pull request](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/pull/1149)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to insert an item to the play list using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification point:

- When `YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert(resource, part)` is used, the arguments are `resource`, `part` which are an object and an array of string, respectively.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert(
  {
    "snippet": {
      "playlistId": "PL5t3YGq3D2WnrLyuYL9WCgprQ2RUcwl8a",
      "position": 0,
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": testVidId
      }
    }
  },
  ["snippet"]
);
```

#### Note:

- Before you use this, [please confirm whether YouTube Data API v3 is enabled at Advanced Google services, again](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

#### Reference:

- [PlaylistItems: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert)